# Using JDBC in Spring application

Tags: spring, jdbc, entitymanager

I am a newbie and am rather lost, would really appreciate some help.

I have a spring application which is currently setup for using JPA - using EntityManager. So the configuration files have something like

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
....
```

Spring injection is used to configure this, so I have a DaoImpl.java file which has

```
@PersistenceContext
protected EntityManager entityManager;
```

and EntityManager can be directly used in this java file.

However, I need to execute some native JDBC queries - EntityManager won't work. So I also need some kind of injection process here. My configuration files have

```
<bean id="dataSource" destroy-method="close"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" primary="true">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url"

 value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@${database.host}:${database.port}:${database.instance}" />
  .....
```

But how can I use some injection process to make jdbc calls please? Can I do so without using jdbcTemplate?

I have already tried to do get an SQL connection from the EntityManager, but I got errors as

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to create transaction on shared EntityManager - use Spring transactions or EJB CMT instead
```

I am trying to execute query

```
BEGIN  ret := f_test(); END;
```

Would really appreciate some help...

Comment: What is wrong with a `JdbcTemplate` this will participate in the current transaction, the only thing you need to do is add a `JdbcTemplate` and be done. Or if you don't want what is it you want, what is it that you cannot do with an `EntityManager.createNativeQuery(<your-query-here>)`>?

Comment: createNativeQuery fails on PL/SQL statements which have an :=. Hibernate can't deal with the :. OK, will look at JdbcTemplate. Thanks very much! I just thought I could just use the JDBC connection without further configuration

Comment: Using JdbcTemplate is easier imho. The `:` in hibernate is used for named parameters so indeed it will not work (you could try escaping them).

Comment: OK, I will try JDBCTemplate. I have tried escaping with \\, it didn't work. (Am I doing something wrong?)

Comment: Maybe you can add the query you are trying to execute to your post. In the meantime try `JdbcTemplate`.

Comment: Have put it in, query is                                                                                                                BEGIN  ret := f_test(); END;

Answer (score 0):

Your entityManagerFactory bean needs additional configuration.

For example:

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="org.springbyexample.orm.repository" />

<bean id="transactionManager" 
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
      p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory"/>

<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="HSQL">
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:/schema.sql" encoding="UTF-8" />
</jdbc:embedded-database>    

<!-- This is how your EM should look like -->
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" 
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
      p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
      p:persistenceUnitName="hsql">
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

You can check it on spring documentation:

http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/spring-data-jpa.html

Comment: Thanks so much! So after I create this xml file, how would I use jdbc?

Comment: That could fit on another question. Take a look at [this example](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/05/spring-jpa-data-hibernate-mysql-maven.html) and [this one](http://java.dzone.com/articles/persistence-layer-spring-31-0)

Comment: I'm totally confused. Shouldn't there be a really easy way to set up a JDBC connection using spring?

Comment: @user2689782 It isn't so straighforward for the xml configuration you need what I posted. For the java code you have to configure your dao objects, take a look at [this](http://www.baeldung.com/2011/12/22/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-data-jpa/). Btw, confirm the answer if it is the solution for your question

Comment: I tried the XML configuration you posted and it did not work. But thanks for helping, I appreciate it! I decided to grab the connection from the existing EntityManager                                         Session session = (Session)entityManager.getDelegate();
Connection conn = session.connection();